# Hide for desk top show for mobile css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create separate page for mobile view it should be hidden for 
 desk top see my css and html whats wrong in this code ?

**Code:**

```
<form class="form-signin-login" method="post" id="login-form">
                    <input type="text" name="user_entered_id" id="user_entered_id" value="Email (or) Phone No" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Email (or) Phone No'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Email (or) Phone No' ) this.value=''">
                     <input type="password" name="lgpassword" id="lgpassword" value="Password" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Password'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Password' ) this.value=''">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Login">
            </form>

 <style>

body{
background-color:#000;} 
    @media screen and (max-width:300px) {

.input[type=text], .input[type=password]{width: 100%;
padding: 12px 20px;
background-color:#000;
color:#fff;
outline:none;
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;

margin: 8px 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px black inset;
-webkit-text-fill-color: white !important;


  }
 }

    </style>
```

Comment: What are you tying to hide? The entire form?

Comment: yes , this  css only for mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just add the following in to css

`.form-signin-login { display: none;}
 @media screen and (max-width:300px) {
    .form-signin-login { display: inline;}
 }`

Here is the working sample :https://jsfiddle.net/6sz8rnb2/1/

[image]

Comment: check the fiddle ,form only display for mobile view

Comment: when you minimize the output section of the jsfiddle you can see result

Comment: of course but  you just try to view in mobile not working

Answer (score 0):

@media add min-width and max-width (for mobil and desktop), to hide use property visibility (value: visible | hidden | collapse | inherit |);Note: All other elements on the page do not change their position.

Comment: use id of the inputs and class button, so https://jsfiddle.net/c05yjgsp/1/